# how to resize/ shrink disk size the KVM disk size in proxmox?

Tags: 14.04

I have convert (P2V) and currently, its VM is running in my proxmox, but the disk size is 1050 GB, I want to resize/ shrink the disk to 400 GB, does anyone know the steps? Can you help me?

The guest OS is Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS (CLI)

thanks.

Best Regards,
Arie

Comment: This will almost certainly be closed as off topic as Proxmox is Debian, not Ubuntu. See http://libguestfs.org/virt-resize.1.html and generally the Proxmox forums are best. https://forum.proxmox.com/

Comment: Yes, i know Proxmox is Debian, but the guest OS is Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS.. and after I ask in forum.proxmox.com, to shrink the disk in execution in guest OS.

Comment: You can do it from the link I gave you or boot a live iso and use gparted, but first link is better.

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/sid/libguestfs-tools

Comment: Can you please include the filesystem type on the 14.04 guest. ext4? ext4 over lvm ? btrfs ? something else?